# why my video playing Anti roitation in some devices of android build with unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, video

*i was playing video in ui panel.
video playing complete nothing any issue.*

**but i am build in android device so i have try within two devices.**

- in device one run play complete
- in second device video playing but in anti rotate

*So what element value i will be change please tell me i will search on google but not found any solution. if any one know than tell me*

**here some image of my video settings and also output ss.**

**In Panel RawImage**

[image]

**VideoPlayer**

[image]

**output**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

**Finally i was found solution**

**Goto [ Player Setting => Other Settings => Auto Graphics API set True ]**

*Show Blow  ScreenShots*

**Old Setting**

[image]

**New Setting**

[image]